# UTF-8 not working over SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, osx, character-encoding

I have configured my terminal on OSX to show emoji properly. When I open up a terminal I can type and see emoji properly. My locale settings for OSX are shown below. When I start a tmux session it works fine as well.

However, when I start up an ssh session to my Ubuntu server emoji is shown as a strange digit. Locale settings for Ubuntu ssh session are also shown below.

I am wondering why this is and how I can fix it. I am using Droid Sans Mono for Powerline as the font in my terminal. OSX version is El Capitan and the version of Ubuntu on my server is 14.04 LTS.

## OSX locale

```
dino :: locale               
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

## Linux locale (via ssh session)

```
testarossa :: ~ %locale              
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

### What an emoji looks like on local session in OSX

[image]

### What the same string looks like on a remote session on my Ubuntu machine

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `TERM` is irrelevant.  What does matter is the terminal emulator (and also the version of glibc).  See for example my comments in [Debian #790847](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=790847):

```
Interestingly, the lynx package in Fedora22 works
(passably with vte
 -- none of the other terminals display Emoji
 -- no need for a list).
```

while (I cannot verify at the moment), Ubuntu 14.04 is likely old enough that the problem which I noted later, in *glibc* is relevant:

```
Further checking in Debian/testing shows me that wcwidth() is returning -1's
for these values (which is incorrect, it should return 1's).  Lynx is behaving
correctly for this case -- it has no way to tell that the characters "should"
print as expected.
```